# Quotient Space Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve the exercise

Let

$c=\{(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}/\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{x_{n}}\ \mathrm{existe}\}$

$c_{0}=\{(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}/\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{x_{n}}=0\}$

Show that

$\mathrm{dim}(c/c_{0})=1$

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

$(1,1,1,...)+c_0$ spans $c/c_0$. Indeed, if $(a_n) \in c$ then $(a_n)+c_0=a[(1,1,...)+c_0]$ where $a=\lim a_n$.